# Why my question about Java date APIs closed?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032051/replace-java-util-date-with-joda-time#comment16060445_12032051) but it got closed before I got any answers. Stack Overflow says it is a Q&A site for all. I couldn't tell from the FAQ why it was closed, so can anyone explain what happened?

Comment: What questions? Without referencing them, this is not answerable (and perhaps some insight into why your unknown questions were closed).

Comment: @TimPost please see my question's link.

Comment: Hi Sai, thanks for taking a constructive approach to getting your question reopened. I hope this demonstrates that the process works, and if you bring your question to meta with an open mind, the community can be quite helpful! I think you just need 1 more reopen vote to get your question opened again. Good luck! :)

Comment: Hey Sai, did you cast a reopen vote on your question? There are 4 votes, and you only need 250 rep to cast a vote on your own questions...

Comment: @jmort253 i already clicked reopen tag. I also included 4 reopen voters.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was expecting this to be a language issue but I didn't really have any problems understanding your questions. It's just that they're very basic *and* rather open-ended. When combined with very short questions with grammatical problems people are inclined to vote down and close rather than spend time improving them.

I was torn on your Joda time vs java.util.Date question because it's a fairly narrowly tailored A vs B question and I think there could be useful answers. There's also a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date) that might be helpful.

Also, when you changed it to

> Is it OK to replace some programs that use java.util.Date to Joda
>   Time?

it wasn't really an improvement because we can't tell what that means. We'd have to know *which* programs in order to answer that in a meaningful way.

Comment: I'm confused, the question you linked is `java.util.date` vs `java.sql.date` and apart from an "obligatory mention" of jodaTime I fail to see the reference.

Comment: @Brad Mace: but strictly speaking that is not the reason that the 5 that voted to close gave him, they said it is not a real question. Compared to what I see everyday get closed this was a near miss, from a user that has answered plenty of questions and has a relatively high rep.

Comment: Hi @carlosdc, high rep doesn't give anyone a free pass to ask off-topic, duplicate, or NARQ questions. If you look at a few of the questions, some of the other ones are downvoted and follow this same pattern of already being found, either on Stack Overflow, or elsewhere. With that said, we're definitely willing to help, and I respect the approach the asker has taken here on meta in regards to addressing his closed question. I believe it's possible to edit and improve it. Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253: I'm not saying that. I'm just saying there is very clearly a continuum between 20 send-me-the-codez in 30 days and this guy. I'm saying that it very clearly is a real question. And I'm not even 100% right now that it is a duplicate.

Comment: @carlosdc - I see what you're saying, but unfortunately, many people look at questions like this and see NARQ. Fortunately, it's clear that the asker cares and is an overall good contributor, and can add a little more detail. With that said, I've voted to reopen too! With the edits, the question looks a *lot* better.  The system works! :)

Answer (score 3):

IMO I have seen many questions (Inluding my own) closed like yours.

The reason is for the use of questions like:

- what are the benefits?
- Which is better?
- Why use..?

That is more for CodeReview, where as you'd expect questions like I am using this, but it won't work etc..

The question you asked would most likely solicit debate, and for some was vague, those were the grounds that IMO the question was closed.

Another good sign if your question will be closed is how long is the question?

Very rare a good question is 2-3 lines.

IMO the question was closed incorrectly as *closed as not a real question* and should have been closed as *Not constructive* (as it would solicit debate, you will only be getting opinions on which API is better not cold facts)

See the FAQ for more:https://stackoverflow.com/faq

> **What kind of questions can I ask here?**
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please look around to see if your question has been asked before. It’s
>   also OK to ask and answer your own question.
>
> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be
>   asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to
>   explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of
>   course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” your
>   answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more
>   answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?” there is no
>   actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I
>   do.” we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if
>   ______ happened?” it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Answer (score 2):

Look around the site at other questions that are asked. Are they short, one-liners like yours?  Or perhaps you see lots of detail, some code?  Did those questions make full usage of the textarea, or did they leave a lot of empty space?

I suspect that much of what you asked could probably be found on Google? Did you do a search before asking "What is Joda time?"

I just did a quick Google search and came up with lots of information about Joda time. Please see [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=joda+time&sugexp=chrome,mod=19&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Now, let's assume you *did* actually search. Did you explain in the question what it was about those other answers on Google that didn't already answer your question? Did you describe in greater detail what the exact problem was you were facing, with code examples, error messages, what you've tried?

It seems like your question was closed because it's just too basic, and on Stack Overflow, we're looking for questions that haven't already been answered on every corner of the Internet.

With that said, consider editing your question. Closure is by no means permanent, and if you improve your question, it can be reopened by the community.  So, tell us what it is that you don't understand. Give us the details so that we don't have to try and dig them out of you. :)  If you do these things, you may find that you also get much better answers to your problems, and many more upvotes. Good luck!

Comment: I put the shortness/bluntness of the question down to a language barrier. As for searching for a result- again, a language barrier could explain a lack of results (on Stackoverflow or Google)

Comment: Hi @Robotnik, that's very possible, and one thing the asker could do is to edit the question and try to explain. It's perfectly okay if one's English isn't perfect. I'd like to think our community is willing to help this person improve the question, if that's what the op wants to do. (In fact, I've seen questions like this get reversed due to questions like this on meta that resulted in community editing.) :)